# Role of * in the numpy.random statement

Tags: python

While exploring color codes in the Matplotlib Library of Python, I came across this piece of code:

```
x,y,c=zip(*np.random.rand(30,3))
```

I looked up the working of the built in function `zip()` in Python, but I do not seem to undertstand the role of `*` before the numpy random statement.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please link to this code (file and line number)? I'd like to fix it.

Comment: This has been closed with the wrong dup. This question is not about asterisks in the paremeter list of a function, it is about iterable unpacking a la PEP448. A better dup is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980992/asterisk-in-tuple-list-and-set-definitions-double-asterisk-in-dict-definition

Comment: @Craig. Added to the list

Answer (score 1):

It is a very weird way to transpose. Same can be achieved with:

```
x,y,c=np.random.rand(3, 30)  # or, np.random.rand(30, 3).T
```

How it works: say, we have an 3x2 array `data = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]`. To transpose it without numpy and get a 2x3 array `[[1,3,5], [2,4,6]]` we can do:

```
data_transposed = list(zip(*data))
```

This is equivalent to:

```
data_transposed = list(zip([1,2], [3,4], [5,6]))
```

`zip` will produce an iterator of , , ... etc. - which will result in a list of: , , ... - i.e., a transpose of `data`

Comment: Might be worth submitting a PR to fix this

Comment: @MadPhysicist agree. Just need a link to the code