# pandas named aggregation without multilevel dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove the multi level but unable to do so.

```
import pandas as pd
k = pd.DataFrame([['x',2], ['y',4],['x',6]], columns=['name','value'])
    
agg_item={'value': [('n', 'count')]}
    
k=k[['name','value']].groupby(['name'],dropna=False).agg(agg_item).reset_index()
k
   name value
           n
0   x   2
1   y   1

k.columns
​

MultiIndex([( 'name',  ''),
            ('value', 'n')],
           )
```

How do I get sql like table with only 'name' and 'n' columns?

Desired output:

```
   name n
0   x   2
1   y   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a list in your dictionary, you request to have a multindex.

You should use this syntax instead:

```
agg_item={'n': ('value', 'count')}
    
(k[['name','value']]
  .groupby(['name'],dropna=False)
  .agg(**agg_item).
  reset_index()
)
```

*NB. Don't forget to unpack the dictionary as parameters*

Or without dictionary:

```
(k[['name','value']]
  .groupby(['name'],dropna=False)
  .agg(n=('value', 'count')).
  reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
  name  n
0    x  2
1    y  1
```

Comment: @mozway what does that '**' mean?

Comment: It means to unpack the dictionary as parameters. Basically turn my first code into the second one.

Comment: @itthrill https://stackoverflow.com/q/36980992/17242583

Answer (score 2):

You can use a named aggregation with `pd.NamedAgg` to avoid creating a MultiIndex in the first place:

```
n_agg = pd.NamedAgg(column='value', aggfunc='count')
k = k[['name','value']].groupby(['name'],dropna=False).agg(n=n_agg).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> k
  name  n
0    x  2
1    y  1
```

Or, as @itthrill suggested, you can use `.agg(n=('value', 'count'))` instead of `pd.NamedAgg`.

Comment: you see that col names are name and value and not name and n

Comment: thanks. I hope I am not doing any mistake in the aggregation itself.

Comment: @itthrill check my answer now.

Comment: k=k[['name','value']].groupby(['name'],dropna=False).agg(n=("value", "count")).reset_index()


k

Comment: Oh yeah, nice! That's even shorter :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to select levels:

```
k.columns = [col[0] if col[1]=='' else col[1] for col in k.columns]
```

you can also use `or` instead of if-else:

```
k.columns = [col[1] or col[0] for col in k.columns]
```

Or you can `droplevel` before `reset_index` in your `groupby`:

```
k=k[['name','value']].groupby(['name'],dropna=False).agg(agg_item).droplevel(0, axis=1).reset_index()
#                                                                  ^ ^ ^ here
```

Output:

```
  name  n
0    x  2
1    y  1
```

Comment: This will work but I need to solve it at root level itself. Most likely I should handle aggregation differently so that named aggregation does not yield in to multi indexes.